# How to convert this excel formula to vuejs script

Tags: vue.js

How to convert this excel formula to vuejs script

```
=$B$23*(1-$B$25)*$B$13*(1-$B$14)*(1+$B$24)^(B36-1)-SUM($B$15:$B$18)*$B$23/$B$22


values

B23=100000,
B25=10%,
B13=9%,
B14=3%,
B24=1%,
B36=1,
B15=6000,
B16=1125,
B17=700,
B18=0,
B22=1000000
```

Result in Excel = 7074.50

```
return this.investmentamount * (1-(this.vacancyrateprecentage/100)) * (this.rentPercentage/100) * (1-(this.managementpercentage/100)) * (1+(this.annualrentalgrowthpercentage/100))^(1-1)-(this.servicecharges+this.repair+this.propertyinsurance+this.vat)*this.investmentamount/this.propertyprice;
```

i will set variables for the values entered in vuejs

i have used "/100" for percentage

My result in vuejs = -7667

Comment: in javascript `^` is bitwise XOR, not power (`**` or `Math.pow`)

Comment: Thank-you verymuch it worked...  :)